# Construct table from list of strings

Tags: string-manipulation, list-manipulation, evaluation

I have data in this form:

```
data={"00:00 08:15 8.25 21", "08:15 10:45 2.50 7", "10:45 12:00 1.25 20",
"12:00 22:00 10.00 1", "22:00 22:15 0.25 23", "22:15 00:00 1.75 5"}
```

I want to construct a table that consists of two columns. The first column would consist of time in format 'HH:MM:SS.SS'. The second column would consist of a category which would be the last number from each of the strings (i.e. 21, 7, 20, 1, 23, 5).

The way it would be calculated would be taking the first and second time from each string as start and end point and each row would represent 0.5 second.

So far example the first 5 rows would look like this:

| Time | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00:00.00 | 21 |
| 00:00:00.50 | 21 |
| 00:00:01.00 | 21 |
| 00:00:01.50 | 21 |
| 00:00:02.00 | 21 |

This would continue until "08:15:00.00" and then would continue with category "7" and so on.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: I cannot understand the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
splitdata = StringSplit /@ data;

dateRanges = 100 Mod[Range[##, 1/2] & @@@ 
   Map[AbsoluteTime, 
     ReplaceAll[{a_, "00:00"} :> {a, "24:00"}] @ splitdata[[All, ;; 2]], {-1}], 
  24 60 60];

toHMSList = StringRiffle[
   Riffle[
     IntegerString[IntegerDigits[#, MixedRadix[{60, 60, 100}], 4], 10, 2], 
     {":", ":", "."}], 
  ""] &;

result = MapThread[Thread @* List, 
   {Map[Map @ toHMSList] @ dateRanges, splitdata[[All, -1]]}];

Length /@ result
```

> ```
> {59401, 18001, 9001, 72001, 1801, 12601}
> ```

First 4 columns:

```
Column[result[[All, ;; UpTo[4]]]]
```

[image]

```
Grid[Prepend[
  Join @@ result[[All, ;; UpTo[4]]], 
  {"Time", "Category"}], 
 Dividers -> {{False, True}, {False, True, {False}}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can use [`DateRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateRange.html) with desired shape for [`$DateStringFormat`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$DateStringFormat.html) to get the same result:

```
splitdata = StringSplit /@ data;

dranges = Map[StringDrop[#, -1] &] @
   Block[{$DateStringFormat = {"Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "SecondExact"}}, 
    Map[Apply[DateRange[##, {1/2, "Second"}] &] @* Map[DateString]] @ 
  ReplaceAll[{a_, "00:00"} :> {a, "24:00"}] @ splitdata[[All, ;; 2]]];

resultB = MapThread[Thread@*List, {dranges, splitdata[[All, -1]]}];

resultB == result
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**Update:** A function that combines all steps:

```
ClearAll[toHMSList, reOrg]

toHMSList = StringRiffle[
   Riffle[IntegerString[IntegerDigits[#, MixedRadix[{60, 60, 100}], 4], 10, 2],
   {":", ":", "."}], ""] &;

reOrg[dat_] := Module[{sd = StringSplit /@ dat, dates, values, dr}, 
  dates = sd[[All, ;; 2]]; values = sd[[All, -1]]; 
  dr = 100 Mod[Range[##, 1/2] & @@@ 
      Map[AbsoluteTime, ReplaceAll[{a_, "00:00"} :> {a, "24:00"}]@dates, {-1}], 
    24 60 60];
  MapAt[toHMSList, MapThread[Thread@*List, {dr, values}], {All, All, 1}]]
```

***Example:***

```
reOrg[data] == result
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, it works well but I just have one problem still. I see for the category 5 data ("22:15 00:00 1.75 5") it is returning nothing whereas it should be 12600 points (i.e. 00:00 - 22:15 = 1.75hrs = 12600 points). I guess it's because there are two instances of "00:00" in the data so doesn't know which comes first. Is there a way to edit the code so it takes this into account? Thanks again

Comment: @wmv, please see the update.

Comment: I maybe worded it badly but that's now too many points for the category 5 data. The data rows for category 5 should be from 22:15 to 00:00 which equates to 1.75hrs of data which in turn equates to 12600 rows. The way i worded it before made it sound like it was from 00:00 to 22:15 which would equate to 22.25 hrs (160201 rows). Thanks again

Comment: @wmv, please see the new version.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: Sorry to come back to you on this but I wonder if you could help me again. I'd like to make this function work for nested list. So if data was for example: data={{"00:00 08:15 8.25 21", "08:15 10:45 2.50 7", "10:45 12:00 1.25 20",
"12:00 22:00 10.00 1", "22:00 22:15 0.25 23", "22:15 00:00 1.75 5"},{"00:00 04:30 4.50 14", "04:30 09:00 4.50 14", "09:00 10:30 1.50 14","10:30 10:45 0.25 14", "10:45 11:00 0.25 14", "11:00 12:00 1.00 21","12:00 13:30 1.50 21", "13:30 17:45 4.25 21", "17:45 19:45 2.00 8","19:45 20:45 1.00 21", "20:45 21:15 0.50 8", "21:15 00:00 2.75 21"}}. Thanks again!

Comment: @wmv, Please see the update. If input data (say, `data2`) is a list of lists, you can use `Map[reOrg]@data2`.

Comment: i tried using the code from update but gives me error: MapThread::mptc: Incompatible dimensions of objects at positions {2, 1} and {2, 2} of MapThread[Thread@*List,{{{0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,<<59391>>},{2970000,2970050,2970100,2970150,2970200,2970250,2970300,2970350,2970400,2970450,<<17991>>},{3870000,3870050,3870100,3870150,3870200,3870250,3870300,3870350,3870400,3870450,<<8991>>},{4320000,4320050,4320100,4320150,4320200,4320250,4320300,4320350,4320400,4320450,<<71991>>},{7920000,7920050,7920100,7920150,7920200,7920250,7920300,7920350,7920400,7920450,<<1791>>},{801000...

Comment: @wmv, sorry; copy/pasted wrong code block. Try the new version.

Comment: that worked perfectly. thanks for all of your amazing help!

Answer (score 5):

Mind you that the list you're asking is large. There are `24*60*60*2` or `172800` half-seconds in a day.

```
data = {"00:00 08:15 8.25 21", "08:15 10:45 2.50 7", "10:45 12:00 1.25 20", "12:00 22:00 10.00 1", "22:00 22:15 0.25 23", "22:15 00:00 1.75 5"};
list2 = {}; (*lists will go in here*)
Do[
   a = StringSplit[data][[i]]; (*split the data points in each string*)
   b = ToExpression[StringSplit[a[[1 ;; 2]], ":"]]; (*separate HH and MM*)
   c = (60*#[[1]] + #[[2]] & /@ b); (*initial & final times, in minute*)
   l = c /. {m0_, m1_} -> (m1 - m0)*(60*2); (*number of 0.5s in-between*)
   list = {}; (*time point with category will go in here*)
   Do[
      x = 50*n; (*.SS*)
      y = c[[1]] + Floor[x/100/60]; (*MM*)
      z1 = {Floor[y/60], Mod[y, 60], Mod[Floor[x/100], 60], Mod[x, 100]}; (*time point*)
      z2 = IntegerString[z1, 10, 2]; (*time point in 2-digit format*)
      AppendTo[list,
               (*{time point string, category number}*)
               {z2[[1]] <> ":" <> z2[[2]] <> ":" <> z2[[3]] <> "." <> z2[[4]], Last@a}
      ];
   , {n, 0, l - 1}];
   AppendTo[list2, list];
, {i, 1, Length@data}]
```

To pick the list corresponding to the first data `"00:00 08:15 8.25 21"`, just do `list2[[1]]` and so on. If you just want the list to be flat, do

```
list2 = Flatten[list2, 1];
```

[image]

The code excludes end data points like `{08:15:00.00, 21}`. If you want to include them as well, change the range of `n` to `{n, 0, l}`.

Comment: Thank you so much! that works perfectly

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, it works well but I just have one problem still. I see for the category 5 data ("22:15 00:00 1.75 5") it is returning nothing whereas it should be 12600 points (i.e. 00:00 - 22:15 = 1.75hrs = 12600 points). I guess it's because there are two instances of "00:00" in the data so doesn't know which comes first. Is there a way to edit the code so it takes this into account? Thanks again